# syntax error in false clause and when I search for names nothing displays

Tags: vb.net

One time when I run this code it run smoothly but then when i search for names there is no record appears. Badly need your help guys for our program project. thanks in advance :)

This is my code :

```
Private Sub search_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles search_btn.Click
    Me.Show()
    Search_Record()

End Sub

Private Sub Search_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

    Try

        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\VB\HSU\HSU\G11B.mdb"

        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sSQL = "SELECT Last_Name, First_Name FROM 10ABM"
        sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE Last_Name like '%" & Me.search_txt.Text & "%'"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No record found!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a classic case of not looking at what's in front of you. Have you looked at the value of `sSQL`?  I'll wager not, because it's not valid SQL code.

Comment: I think you have not included any space before the `WHERE` class. So now your query is like `SELECT Last_Name, First_Name FROM 10ABMWHERE Last_Name.....`

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran Although you're right about the missing space, the OP should **Not** _just_ add that space. Instead, they should use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/4934172) to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yeah that's correct

Comment: Just to add my 2-pence.... don't forget to `dispose` your `cmd`, you have `conn.close`, thats good, always use `cmd.dispose` as well with that... just a good habit to get into! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for helping. Im just a beginner using vb.net for our project.